# View is not receiving POST data from form

Tags: python, django

My view is not receiving any of the POST data I am sending from a login form.

To test out the submission, I want to output the email field to the browser.

The output being returned from the view is `None`

**login.html**

```
        <form action="/login_email/" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**views.py**

```
def login_email(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password')

    return HttpResponse(email)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no name field in your input tags.

**Change your html to something like this...Please note the name attribute with the input tag, that's most important.**

```
<form action="/login_email/" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Password</label>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: How embarrassing - been a long day. Thanks!